# Display clickable images using repeater in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to display a list of images and on clicking any image, it will get replaced by an "X" image.

So far, I have been able to display the list, but I am not able to make them clickable.

**C# code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Cards"));
    List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());

    foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
    {
        images.Add(String.Format("~/Cards/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
    }

    RepeaterImages.DataSource = images;
    RepeaterImages.DataBind();
}
```

**ASPX Content**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterImages" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="currentImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' onclick='changeImage()'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Instead of using <asp:Image> use an <asp:ImageButton> control, also have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx for using arguments, just don't forget to give your repeater a OnItemCommand="RepeaterImages_ItemCommand"

Comment: Is `changeImage()` a JavaScript function?

Comment: @Codingman where is your JS and why are you not using the image button if you want to make image clickable ?

Comment: <asp:HyperLink /> also takes a ImageUrl incase it's link functionality you want. Or your javascript might just need to set mousepointer on hover

Comment: @Codingman If it is JavaScript, whereabouts is it in your question? It's not clear what part you're having difficulty getting to work.